# reactjs dynamic line chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, linechart

Good evening everyone,

I am creating a dynamic line chart, where I process the data received from the Api and pass it to the chart, but no lines are generated when I save the data in usestate. But if I create a const with a list of objects, and pass it to the graph it works perfectly, does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Code Reacjs App.

ProductionTableDailyChart

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Spinner, Form, Row, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
    LineChart,
    Line,
    XAxis,
    YAxis,
    CartesianGrid,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ResponsiveContainer,
} from "recharts";
import moment from "moment";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import ProductionTableLineChart from "./ProductionTableLineChart";

const ProductionTableDailyChart = ({ uniqueProjects }) => {
    const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);
    const [activities, setActivities] = useState([]);
    const [selectedProjects, setSelectedProjects] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedProjects")) || [],
    );
    const [selectedActivity, setSelectedActivity] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem("selectedActivity") || "",
    );
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem("startDate") ||
            moment().subtract(7, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    );
    const [finishDate, setFinishDate] = useState(
        localStorage.getItem("finishDate") || moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    );
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem(
            "selectedProjects",
            JSON.stringify(selectedProjects),
        );
    }, [selectedProjects]);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("selectedActivity", selectedActivity);
    }, [selectedActivity]);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("startDate", startDate);
    }, [startDate]);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("finishDate", finishDate);
    }, [finishDate]);

    const handleProjectChange = (selectedOptions) => {
        console.log(selectedOptions);
        setSelectedProjects(selectedOptions.map((option) => option.value)); // Extrair os valores dos objetos selecionados
    };

    const handleActivityChange = (e) => {
        setSelectedActivity(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleStartDateChange = (e) => {
        setStartDate(e.target.value);
    };

    const handleFinishDateChange = (e) => {
        setFinishDate(e.target.value);
    };

    const fetchChartData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);

        if (selectedProjects.length === 0) {
            toast.error("Os campo projeto é obrigatório.");
            setIsLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        if (selectedActivity === "") {
            toast.error("Os campo atividade é obrigatório.");
            setIsLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        try {
            const promises = selectedProjects.map(async (project) => {
                const endpoint = project
                    ? `/api/production/getperiodProduction/${startDate}/${finishDate}/${project.name}`
                    : `/api/production/getperiodProduction/${startDate}/${finishDate}/`;
                const response = await axios.get(endpoint);
                const processedData = processActivityData(
                    response.data,
                    project,
                );
                return processedData;
            });

            const chartData = await Promise.all(promises);

            const combinedChartData = chartData.reduce((result, data) => {
                data.forEach((entry) => {
                    if (entry.project) {
                        // Check if entry.project exists
                        const existingEntry = result.find(
                            (item) => item.date === entry.date,
                        );
                        if (existingEntry) {
                            existingEntry["P" + entry.project.id] =
                                entry.accumulatedValue;
                        } else {
                            const newEntry = {
                                date: entry.date,
                                ["P" + entry.project.id]:
                                    entry.accumulatedValue,
                                name: entry.name,
                            };
                            result.push(newEntry);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return result;
            }, []);

            setChartData(combinedChartData);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching chart data:", error);
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    };

    const processActivityData = (activities, project) => {
        let selectedActivityData = activities.find(
            (item) => item.activitie === selectedActivity,
        );

        if (!selectedActivityData || !selectedActivityData.dailyProduction) {
            console.error(
                "No valid dailyProduction data found for the selected activity.",
            );
            return [];
        }

        let accumulated = 0;

        const dailyProduction = selectedActivityData.dailyProduction;
        const processedData = Object.entries(dailyProduction)
            .sort(([date1], [date2]) => new Date(date1) - new Date(date2))
            .map(([date, quantity]) => {
                quantity = Number(quantity);
                accumulated += isNaN(quantity) ? 0 : quantity;
                return {
                    date: moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
                    ["P" + project.id]: accumulated,
                    name: project.name,
                };
            });

        return processedData;
    };

    const fetchActivities = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get("/api/markers");
            setActivities(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching activities:", error);
        }
    };

    const getRandomColor = () => {
        const letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        let color = "#";
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchActivities();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedActivity) {
            fetchChartData();
        }
    }, [selectedActivity, selectedProjects]);

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    height: "100vh",
                }}
            >
                <Spinner animation="border" />
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Row className="mb-3 align-items-end">
                <Col md={5}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="projectDropdown">
                        <Form.Label>Selecione o Projeto:</Form.Label>
                        <Select
                            options={uniqueProjects.map((project) => ({
                                value: project,
                                label: project.name,
                            }))}
                            isMulti
                            onChange={handleProjectChange}
                            value={selectedProjects.map((project) => ({
                                value: project,
                                label: project.name,
                            }))}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col md={2}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="activityDropdown">
                        <Form.Label>Selecione a Atividade:</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            as="select"
                            onChange={handleActivityChange}
                            value={selectedActivity}
                        >
                            <option value="">Todas as Atividades</option>
                            {activities.map((activity) => (
                                <option
                                    key={activity.id}
                                    value={activity.atividade}
                                >
                                    {activity.atividade}
                                </option>
                            ))}
                        </Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col md={2}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="startDate">
                        <Form.Label>Data Inicial</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="date"
                            required
                            value={startDate}
                            onChange={handleStartDateChange}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col md={2}>
                    <Form.Group controlId="finishDate">
                        <Form.Label>Data Final</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                            type="date"
                            required
                            value={finishDate}
                            onChange={handleFinishDateChange}
                        />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Col>
                <Col md={2}>
                    <Button
                        onClick={fetchChartData}
                        variant="primary"
                        style={{ marginTop: "32px" }}
                    >
                        Atualizar Gráfico
                    </Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>

            <ProductionTableLineChart
                chartData={chartData}
                selectedProjects={selectedProjects}
            />

            {/* <div style={{ width: "100%", height: 600 }}>
                {chartData && selectedProjects.length > 0 ? (
                    <ResponsiveContainer>
                        <LineChart data={chartData}>
                            <XAxis dataKey="date" style={{ fontSize: "8px" }} />
                            <YAxis />
                            <CartesianGrid
                                stroke="#eee"
                                strokeDasharray="5 5"
                            />
                            <Tooltip />
                            <Legend />
                            {selectedProjects.map((project) => (
                                <Line
                                    key={project.id}
                                    type="monotone"
                                    dataKey={`P${project.id}`}
                                    stroke={getRandomColor()}
                                    name={project.name}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </LineChart>
                    </ResponsiveContainer>
                ) : (
                    <p>Carregando dados ou nenhum projeto selecionado...</p>
                )}
            </div> */}
            <ToastContainer />
        </>
    );
};

export default ProductionTableDailyChart;


import React from "react";
import {
    LineChart,
    Line,
    XAxis,
    YAxis,
    CartesianGrid,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    ResponsiveContainer,
} from "recharts";

const getRandomColor = () => {
    const letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    let color = "#";
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
};

const data1 = [
    {
        date: "01-10-2023",
        P4: 0,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "02-10-2023",
        P4: 1,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "03-10-2023",
        P4: 2,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "04-10-2023",
        P4: 4,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "05-10-2023",
        P4: 6,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "06-10-2023",
        P4: 8,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "07-10-2023",
        P4: 8,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "08-10-2023",
        P4: 8,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "09-10-2023",
        P4: 8,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "10-10-2023",
        P4: 10,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "11-10-2023",
        P4: 11,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "12-10-2023",
        P4: 11,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "13-10-2023",
        P4: 12,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "14-10-2023",
        P4: 16,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "15-10-2023",
        P4: 16,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "16-10-2023",
        P4: 18,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "17-10-2023",
        P4: 19,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "18-10-2023",
        P4: 19,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "19-10-2023",
        P4: 23,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "20-10-2023",
        P4: 26,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "21-10-2023",
        P4: 27,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "22-10-2023",
        P4: 27,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "23-10-2023",
        P4: 27,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "24-10-2023",
        P4: 31,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "25-10-2023",
        P4: 32,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "26-10-2023",
        P4: 35,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "27-10-2023",
        P4: 37,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "28-10-2023",
        P4: 37,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "29-10-2023",
        P4: 37,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "30-10-2023",
        P4: 37,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
    {
        date: "31-10-2023",
        P4: 38,
        name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
    },
];

const ProductionTableLineChart = ({ chartData, selectedProjects }) => {
    // Gerar uma string única baseada no conteúdo de chartData.
    // Isso pode ser um timestamp ou um identificador único derivado dos dados.
    const chartKey = JSON.stringify(chartData);

    return (
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: 600 }}>
            {chartData && selectedProjects.length > 0 ? (
                <ResponsiveContainer key={chartKey}>
                    <LineChart data={chartData}>
                        <XAxis dataKey="date" style={{ fontSize: "8px" }} />
                        <YAxis />
                        <CartesianGrid stroke="#eee" strokeDasharray="5 5" />
                        <Tooltip />
                        <Legend />
                        {selectedProjects.map((project) => (
                            <Line
                                key={project.id}
                                type="monotone"
                                dataKey={`P${project.id}`}
                                stroke={getRandomColor()}
                                name={project.name}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </LineChart>
                </ResponsiveContainer>
            ) : (
                <p>Carregando dados ou nenhum projeto selecionado...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProductionTableLineChart;
```

In code have Array list

```
const data1 = [
{
    date: "01-10-2023",
    P4: 0,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "02-10-2023",
    P4: 1,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "03-10-2023",
    P4: 2,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "04-10-2023",
    P4: 4,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "05-10-2023",
    P4: 6,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "06-10-2023",
    P4: 8,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "07-10-2023",
    P4: 8,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "08-10-2023",
    P4: 8,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "09-10-2023",
    P4: 8,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "10-10-2023",
    P4: 10,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "11-10-2023",
    P4: 11,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "12-10-2023",
    P4: 11,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "13-10-2023",
    P4: 12,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "14-10-2023",
    P4: 16,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "15-10-2023",
    P4: 16,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "16-10-2023",
    P4: 18,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "17-10-2023",
    P4: 19,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "18-10-2023",
    P4: 19,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "19-10-2023",
    P4: 23,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "20-10-2023",
    P4: 26,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "21-10-2023",
    P4: 27,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "22-10-2023",
    P4: 27,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "23-10-2023",
    P4: 27,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "24-10-2023",
    P4: 31,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "25-10-2023",
    P4: 32,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "26-10-2023",
    P4: 35,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "27-10-2023",
    P4: 37,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "28-10-2023",
    P4: 37,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "29-10-2023",
    P4: 37,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "30-10-2023",
    P4: 37,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
},
{
    date: "31-10-2023",
    P4: 38,
    name: "LT 500 kV ENG. LECHUGA - EQUADOR-T2B",
}];
```